# Kicked back to login screen when logging in

Tags: xorg, lightdm

So I thought I had finally solved my woes about Cinnamon glitching out (occasionally) when trying to run full-screen games. I set up an alias for `'sudo service lightdm restart; sudo startx'`. It worked a few times when something crashed or glitched and I had to ctrl+alt+f2. But now I seem to have screwed something up, because trying to log in from the lightdm login screen on 12.04 shows a familiar screen with some weirdly indented text, and then kicks me back to the login screen without explanation. I've tried removing `~/.Xauthority` and then doing the same command as above, but that didn't work. Good thing I left the guest account enabled.

Any suggestions?

Shows what I get for mucking around with things I don't fully understand. But I'll try to learn from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was only using the wrong command. When I deleted `~/.Xauthority`, I needed to next run `sudo service lightdm restart`, without using `startx`. A learning experience indeed.

Comment: so issue gone ?

Comment: Yup, it's just vanished.