# logging in kicks me back to login screen, 14.04

Tags: unity, xorg, login

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, I've got a Gigabyte gtx-960 gpu and [nvidia drivers installed](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2263316). Yesterday I set up Synergy, and it was working smoothly.
Today once I get to the login screen, every time I log in, it flashes a black screen and returns me to the login screen.

In my limited experience, it seems like xorg is crashing immediately. I've tried the solutions I could find here, including:

- logging into a different user (same problem)
- creating a new user (same problem)
- logging in via `ctrl+alt+Fn` (n = {1-6}) and then doing the following
- [delete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215608/kicked-out-when-logged-in) the [.Xauthority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248049/kicked-back-to-login-screen-when-logging-in) file
- reinstalling [unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367260/i-am-logged-out-immediately-after-logging-in)
- switch to gdm (which actually made things worse: just gives me a black screen, whenever I hit `ctrl+alt+F3` or something, the appropriate screen will show for ~10 seconds, then go black again. I can run commands during that time, and so could switch back to lightdm, but when I type on a black screen, it doesn't do anything).
- edit: tried switching to gnome and xubuntu, no luck. This time before kicking me out a pop-up with "System program problem detected - Do you want to report the problem now?"

I've checked .xsession-errors, although honestly I'm not too sure what to make of it... in case it's useful, here's the output:

```
xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Script for ibus started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2791) terminated with status 1
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: unity-settings-daemon main process(2781) killed by TERM signal
init: logrotate main process (2688) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/lightdm.0.crash) main process (2722) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_compiz.1000.crash) main process (2729) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_ibus-ui-gtk3.1000.crash) main process (2732) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_ibus_ibus-ui-gtk3.1002.crash) main process (2738) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_sbin_vbetool.0.crash) main process (2744) killed by TERM signal
init: xsession-init main process (2778) killed by TERM signal
init: hud main process (2785) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
init: indicator-bluetooth main process (2883) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-datetime main process (2889) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-sound main process (2891) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-printers main process (2894) killed by TERM signal
```

Comment: I didn't find a direct solution. I eventually simply reinstalled ubuntu, which kept most of my files. Had to reinstall some thing, including dependencies, but it was alright. So far working all right.

Comment: Now, after a couple months, the same issue popped up again. If anyone has a solution, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, I think the issue was linked to synergy. After re-installing and not installing that, it hasn't crashed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with your Desktop Environment. Use the `tty login` to install an alternative DE, such as gnome or KDE. Then try logging in via `lightdm` or `gdm`(whichever you use) and install the Desktop Environment that you are comfortable with. I had the same issue a while back and I managed to solve it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that but it didn't work.